# How to apply arithmetic operations between identical values of a variable shared between 2 datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 df which I want to compare by their values of their "element" variable (both share the same values as they derive from a single melted df)

#dummy dfs

```
X3500um_no_touch <- data.frame(element= c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3" ), distance = c(4, 4, 8, 8, 7, 7), mean_raw = c(1794, 1794, 5794, 5794, 1754, 1754))

X3500um_touch <- data.frame(element= c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3" ), distance = c(4, 4, 4, 8, 7, 7), mean_raw = c(1894, 1894, 1894, 4794, 754, 754))
```

I am looking for a way to end up with such a dataset, but I don't know how to proceed:

```
#new_df
element distance mean_raw
1       4        100       # 1894 - 1794
2       8        -1000     # 4794 - 5794
3       7        -1000     # 754 - 1754
```

since the values in element do not align, I cant just do

```
new_df$element <- df2$element - df1$element
```

Any simple way to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is an element and distance in each data frame that is in the other and they are ordered the same way but the problem is just that there are duplicates (which is the case in the question) we can use `unique` on both data frames and then subtract:

```
transform(unique(X3500um_no_touch), mean_raw = unique(X3500um_touch)$mean_raw - mean_raw)
##   element distance mean_raw
## 1       1        4      100
## 3       2        8    -1000
## 5       3        7    -1000
```